# Only keep a part of the 'id' string before a pattern ("_")

Tags: python, string, pandas

I have a little issue here:

I actually have a fasta file such:

```
g1.t1_0035_0042
ATTAGGAGGAA
g2.t1_0042_0042
ATTAGGAGA
g3.t1_0042_0035
ATTGGAAT
etc
```

and what I would liek is only to get the first part of the id name, I used:

```
for record in SeqIO.parse(sp1_aa_corrected, 'fasta'):
    print(record.id[record.id.index("_")::-1])
```

but I get:

```
t.1g
t.2g
t.2g
```

and I would like to get:

```
g1.t1
g2.t1
g3.t1
```

without the `_number_number`
Thanks for your help.

another question: 
If I have a dataframe such :

```
gene_name   scaf_name       scaf_length cov_depth       GC
g3.t1       scaffold 6      56786         79            0.39
g4.t1       scaffold 6      56786         79            0.39
g1.t1       scaffold 256    789765        86            0.42
g2.t1       scaffold 890    3456          85            0.40
g5.t1       scaffold 1234   590           90            0.41
```

and if I want to extract only the raw corresponding to the gene_name: "g2.t1", and creat a new dataframe, here for exemple:

```
gene_name   scaf_name       scaf_length cov_depth       GC
g2.t1       scaffold 890    3456          85            0.40
```

How could I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `str.split` to split by a specific character. In this case, you can also specify `maxsplit=1`. Since this returns a list, you need to index the first element.

```
x = 'g1.t1_0035_0042'

res = x.split('_', maxsplit=1)[0]

print(res)

g1.t1
```

---

To filter your dataframe, just use:

```
res = df[df['gene_name'] == 'g2.t1']
```